# How to update linked file without build

Tags: visual-studio

I've added a shared javascript file as a linked file to a project.  Currently, the contents of the linked file get copied to my local directory on every build.

I'd like to update the linked file without rebuilding the entire project.

```
/sharedLibrary
    /somefile.js

/myProject
    /somefile.js (linked to sharedLibrary/somefile.js)
```

To recreate, Add Existing File, browse to sharedLibrary/somefile.js, click the down arrow next to "Add", and select Add as Link.

At this point, until you build the project, /myProject/somefile.js will not exist.  After the build, it's copied over.

I want to have it copied over without invoking a full build of the project.

Comment: How are you hosting the site? If you're using local IIS or the dev webserver, they should be pointing at the correct location if you launch the site with a debugger attached. Try debugging the site, editing the JS and the reloading the page (while still debugging). At least, that works for MVC. I haven't done webforms in quite some time.

Comment: I've clarified the question

Comment: One further clarification... You want it copied over without building - the first time? Or any time the file is changed externally?

Comment: It doesn't need to be automatic, or the first time, or any time it changes.  When you edit the linked file, you are actually editing the file in it's original location.  Having the linked file copy on save would be great.  But any solution that doesn't require me to build the project is satisfactory.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of any way to do that out of the box, however, writing a tiny app to monitor the `.sln` file and pick out the linked files, then perform the copy should be fairly trivial. In addition, you could then use  a FileSystemWatcher to detect saves and recopy. Unload the project, then right-click and edit. You should be able to see a node like this: `<Content Include="{Absolute Path}"><Link>{Local name}</Link></Content>`. Parsing that should be fairly easy. Not ideal, but it may be sufficient for your needs.